# nohup Command Not Completing The Job

Tags: php, linux, debian, nohup

I am using Debian Linux 64Bit 4Gb RAM 2 CPU VPS Server.
I am executing 50 PHP files using 50 nohup commands and saving their logs.
I watched that all the given jobs not fully completing. Its stopped at 30% sometimes 50% sometimes at 90%.
Previously I thought its happening due to less RAM. then I checked the RAM, only 1gb used. 3gb free RAM.
So I am definitely sure that its not happening due to less RAM.

So whats wrong ?
Why my given jobs not fully completing ?
When I use manually it's working fine. Taking 30 minutes.
But in nohup its stopped at 30%,40%,60%.

Please help. How can I solve the problems. 
Thank you.

Comment: Check your PHP error logs. Also PHP has its own memory limit that's set in php.ini

Comment: ya... i know.. my memory limit is 3072M
also i used set_time_ limit(0);